# Get quantitative value for color on two-color scale

Tags: python, algorithm, colors, interpolation, linear-gradients

I have run a chemical test that produces a color depending on how much of a given chemical is in the sample. It is green if there is no chemical, and yellow if there is a saturating amount of chemical. I have used my camera to take pictures of several samples, and also developed a standard curve, where I add known amounts of chemical to the test, and take pictures of the results to compare the color of the result of my sample to these standards.

What I would like to do, is develop an algorithm that creates a two-color scale. One color is the test without any chemical (green), and the other color is the test saturated with chemical (yellow). And then when I input a sample color, the algorithm gives me a % Yellow output.

I have seen people try to create a gradient between to colors, but never read of someone trying to place colors onto that gradient.

I am already able to get the RGB color values of all my samples, so the actaul algorithm is fairly independent of any programming language (although I am familiar with C, C#, VBA, and python).

Can someone point me to a resource to do what I want to do?

Thank you,

Michael

Comment: Beware that camera calibration is going to be a real issue. Even the same camera will vary its response due to lighting changes.

Comment: add the sample images and concentrations so we can see the dependence ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **create table/function `RGB = f(concentration)`**

   It is the opposite of what you want to do. The idea is to convert some continuous scalar variable (`concentration`) to **RGB** color (with some physical meaning). Here some examples of mine for this:

   - [RGB values of visible spectrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214)
   - [Star B-V color index to apparent RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630970/2521214)
2. **Camera calibration**

   As Mark Ransom suggested this step is necessary. I would try to place some markers in the view area to help with this. For example something like:

   [image: markers]

   Now pick the colors in the corner markers, compute how match they differ to your marker real colors and interpolate the whole image bilinear-ly. If you need bi-cubic (much better results) then use 16 markers. This process is very similar to this:

   - [Enhancing dynamic range and normalizing illumination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31558803/2521214)

   You will need to experiment what markers to use (just black&white, or just green&yellow or black&red&green&blue or combinations ...) so your results will keep the same for varying light conditions. Also you have to make the dependency shots you will base the **#1** on again with markers because without them you could have errors in results ...

   Calibration step can be avoided only if your camera is pre-calibrated, the indicator is always the same color,material,roughness,shininess,... and the image is taken with uniformly constant illumination conditions (inside some box,same bulbs,same exposition,same pupil...) without any shadows,spots,etc... Setups like that are **very expensive**. The low cost hand held devices are around **$10000 USD** (usually used for color detection/testing in manufacturing to calibrate machines).
3. **conversion `concentration = f(RGB)`**

   If the dependency in **#1** is some kind of simple function then you can make its inverse algebraically and use it directly. If you construct the **RGB** diagrams as in the linked **QA**'s you will see which channel(s) to use as input (sometimes you need just one).

   If the dependency is too complicated or not a function then you can use:

   - [approximation search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29166819/2521214)
   - **LUT** (look up table) to find 2 closest matches and interpolate
   - [Reverse complex 2D lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29227551/2521214)

   In case the dependency is strictly **non-increasing** or **non-decreasing** you can also use **binary-search** for this.

Comment: I will have to spend a little bit of time playing around with this. I had suspected that such a tool would already exist--either as a python library or an script for ImageJ. I guess I will have to build my own tool.