# How to get points of a Curve (Shape)

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, curve, cubic

I have a CubicCurve in Java which is defined by 4 control points. I can draw the resulting shape, but how can I receive efficient every point in a given resolution of this shape?
By the way PathIterator "only" returns the control points but not the points of the curve itself.

Comment: What is the reason to have array of curve points?
For most of common tasks (to detect if point is on the curve, to find a point of intersection with line, to animate over a curve) there is a formula typically.

Comment: In my case I want to use the curve data to apply a gamma correction based on this curve. So I need as much discrete points as possible.

Comment: So here you really need not points but transfer function `newBrightness=f(oldBrightness)`.

Comment: show the code where you are trying to get the PathIterator

Comment: final PathIterator iterator = curve.getPathIterator(null);
               while( ! iterator.isDone() ) {
                  final double[] coords = new double[6];
                  iterator.currentSegment(coords);
                  logger.info(coords[0] + "x" + coords[1] + " " + coords[2] + "x" + coords[3] + " " + coords[4] + "x" + coords[5]);
                  iterator.next();
               }

Answer (score 0):

**2D** parametric cubic curves are just two polynomials

```
 x(t)=ax0+ax1*t+ax2*t*t+ax3*t*t*t
 y(t)=ay0+ay1*t+ay2*t*t+ay3*t*t*t
```

where `t=<0.0,1.0>` so you compute the `a?0...a?3` coefficients from control points and then just loop `t` with as small step as you need to get all the points you need for example `dt=1.0/(n-1)` where `n` is the number of points.

The coefficients depends on curve used for **BEZIER/SPLINE or interpolation** see:

- [Proper implementation of cubic spline interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20517874/2521214)

Comment: I am afraid the coefficients you are using in the formula are not the same as used for the CubicCurve in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/CubicCurve2D.html#constructor_summary

Comment: @Thomas Then use what you have ... If you can then extract the coefficients  from the shape you do not need to compute them. The polynomial equations `x(t),y(t)` will be the same. The only thing that could change is the interval of `t`