# How to join two Bezier curve using C1 continuity?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math, cubic-bezier

How to draw Two Cubic Bezier Curve using 8 Points
The last point of the first curve will be the starting point of second curve

What I am doing wrong ??

Please Help me solve this issue .

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<glm::vec3> pointToDraw;

std::vector<glm::vec3> myControlPoints = {
    glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f),
};

#define numVBOs 1
#define numVAOs 1
GLuint VBO[numVBOs];
GLuint VAO[numVAOs];

GLuint renderingProgram;

bool checkOpenGLError() {
    bool foundError = false;
    int glErr = glGetError();
    while (glErr != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        cout << "glError: " << glErr << endl;
        foundError = true;
        glErr = glGetError();
    }
    return foundError;
}

void printShaderLog(GLuint shader) {
    int len = 0;
    int chWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
    if (len > 0) {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, len, &chWrittn, log);
        cout << "Shader Info Log: " << log << endl;
        free(log);
    }
}

void printProgramLog(int prog) {
    int len = 0;
    int chWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
    if (len > 0) {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, len, &chWrittn, log);
        cout << "Program Info Log: " << log << endl;
        free(log);
    }
}

string readShaderSource(const char* filePath) {
    string content;
    ifstream fileStream(filePath, ios::in);
    string line = "";

    while (!fileStream.eof()) {
        getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }
    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}

GLuint createShaderProgram()
{
    GLint vertCompiled;
    GLint fragCompiled;
    GLint linked;

    string vertShaderStr = readShaderSource("vertexShader.glsl");
    string fragShaderStr = readShaderSource("fragmentShader.glsl");

    GLuint vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    const char* vertShaderSrc = vertShaderStr.c_str();
    const char* fragShaderSrc = fragShaderStr.c_str();

    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vertShaderSrc, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fragShaderSrc, NULL);

    glCompileShader(vShader);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertCompiled);
    if (vertCompiled != 1) {
        cout << "vertex compilation failed" << endl;
        printShaderLog(vShader);
    }

    glCompileShader(fShader);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fragCompiled);
    if (fragCompiled != 1) {
        cout << "fragment compilation failed" << endl;
        printShaderLog(fShader);
    }

    // Shader program objektum létrehozása. Eltároljuk az ID értéket.
    GLuint vfProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, vShader);
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, fShader);

    glLinkProgram(vfProgram);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetProgramiv(vfProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if (linked != 1) {
        cout << "linking failed" << endl;
        printProgramLog(vfProgram);
    }

    glDeleteShader(vShader);
    glDeleteShader(fShader);

    return vfProgram;
}



int NCR(int n, int r) {

    if (r == 0) return 1;

    if (r > n / 2) return NCR(n, n - r);

    long res = 1;

    for (int k = 1; k <= r; ++k) {
        res *= n - k + 1;
        res /= k;
    }

    return res;
}

GLfloat blending(GLint n, GLint i, GLfloat t) {
    return NCR(n, i) * pow(t, i) * pow(1.0f - t, n - i);
}

void drawBezierCurve(std::vector<glm::vec3> controlPoints) {

    glm::vec3   nextPoint;
    GLfloat     t = 0.0f, B;
    GLfloat     increment = 1.0f / 100.0f; 

    while (t <= 1.0f) {
        nextPoint = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < controlPoints.size(); i++) {
            B = blending(controlPoints.size() - 1, i, t);
            nextPoint.x += B * controlPoints.at(i).x;
            nextPoint.y += B * controlPoints.at(i).y;
            nextPoint.z += B * controlPoints.at(i).z;
        }

        pointToDraw.push_back(nextPoint);
        t += increment;
    }
}

void init(GLFWwindow* window) {
    renderingProgram = createShaderProgram();

    drawBezierCurve(myControlPoints);

    glGenBuffers(numVBOs, VBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(numVAOs, VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointToDraw.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), pointToDraw.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glUseProgram(renderingProgram);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

    glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);

    glLineWidth(2.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, pointToDraw.size());

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I want to join two cubic Bezier curve
[Two Cubic Bezier Curve Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY1EE.png)

Second curve is starting from the end of first cubic Bezier curve

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions, or any questions that are not C.

Comment: This link gets a good explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2835109/654647. SO has a dozens of answers on this typical question.

Comment: see bullet #1 in [point call sequence and BEZIER cubic as interpolation cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20517874/2521214) its example of 10 points piecewise cubic curve ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper implementation of cubic spline interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303172/proper-implementation-of-cubic-spline-interpolation)